# How do I get values of checkboxes?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I'm using Drupal 7 and have added checkboxes to a node.

```
$results = query();

foreach ($results as $result) {
  $name = $result['name'];
  $resultarray[$result['id']] = $name; 
}

$form['friends'] = array(
  '#title' => "results",
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $resultarray,
);
```

On my node the checkboxes show.

Now I'm struggling to get the values of selected checkboxes.

```
function friendmodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $friends = $form_state['values']['friends'];

  // do what ever with $friends 
}
```

But nothing displays. I've tried echo `$friends`, `print_r`, display them as a Drupal message, but nothing is showing.

What should I do to get the values of selected checkboxes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that your `$resultarray` variable in the form actually has some data in it, this code will get you a list of the ids that have been selected:

```
function friendmodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {   
  $friend_ids = array_filter($form_state['values']['friends']);
}
```

When a `checkboxes` element is submitted all of the original option keys will be in the `$form_state['values']'friends']` array, but only the ones that have been selected will have a positive value; the rest will have a value of zero, so you need to use `array_filter()` to extract only the IDs for options that *have* been selected.

Also, at the moment you have a syntax error in your submit function (an extra closing `)`), maybe that's what is causing the error.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said but now im getting Notice: Undefined index: values and array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array

Comment: That means your `$form_state['values']` array is empty which would indicate quite a big problem with the form. Can you post the exact code you're using for the form and the submit function (including the function declaration itself)?

Comment: Beware that using this code all values from 'friends' that evaluate as false in PHP will not be retrieved. This includes for example the value "0".

Answer (score 0):

#### Drupal 8

If I have checkboxes "Friends" and options are like

```
[ ] abc
[ ] def
[ ] ghi
[ ] jkl
```

And I want to know which options user have marked, then use below function.

```
if ($form_state->getValue('friends') != NULL) {

  foreach ($form_state->getValue('friends') as $key => $value) {

    if ($value != 0) {

      $friends = $friends . ", " . $key;
      $friends = substr_replace($friends, "", 0, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

If user has chosen `abc` and `ghi` then you will get `1`, `3` as result in `$friends`. If you wanted to know the value then use

```
$friends = $friends . ", " . $value;
```

It worked for me. I hope it will help you as well.